# My 2013 Nissan Versa has 176,000 miles and runs perfectly except when I go up a steep hill

Tags: cvt-transmission

If I exceed 4000rpms  on a hill the engine will rev out of control and I must pull over and shut off the car and recrank it to restore it to running normally.If Ican keep it under 4000rpms until I reach flat ground it runs perfectly. Does my CVT need reflashing at the dealership or coulit be sensor that doesnt like the elevation  change? It never happens  going  downhill.Sure would appreciate an "educated" guess! Thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

My educated guess is its just getting up there in age and is starting to slip due to the added stress of having to go up hill. This would explain why it doesn't slip downhill as it is just coasting.